# Importing file in .pch gives "receiver for class is a forward declaration"

Tags: xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I created a custom class that I want available everywhere, so I imported it in my app-Prefix.pch file under `#ifdef __OBJC__`

However, whenever I open any class, I get an error `receiver for class is a forward declaration`, but the project still builds just fine. The errors go away after building, but once I start editing the code again, all the errors come back.

The errors never actually stop my program from building and don't cause any actual errors, they are just extremely annoying and uncomfortable. Xcode knows damn well that the files are available, it's just trying to mess with me.

I'm using Xcode 4.5.1 and ARC.